# Proof verification: Prove that the product of $2$ real negative numbers is positive.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> Can someone please verify any mistakes in my proof of this theorem. Is this a correct proof of the corollary of $(-1)\times (-1) = 1$ that the product of two negative numbers is positive?

**Theorem**: *The product of two real negative numbers is positive*

*Proof:* Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R^+}$. We have

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
(-1) \times0=0\quad
\Rightarrow\quad &&
  (-1) \times (-xy+xy)            &= 0
\\
\Rightarrow\quad &&
  (-1)\times((-1)\times xy+xy)&= 0
\\
\Rightarrow\quad &&
                        (-1)\times(-1)\times xy+(-1)\times xy &= 0 \\ \Rightarrow\quad && (-1)\times x \times (-1) \times y +(-1)\times xy&=0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad &&(-x)\times (-y)- xy&=0 \\
\Rightarrow\quad &&(-x)\times (-y)&=xy.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct, but perhaps this would be faster. Take any two negative number $x$ and $y$. Then $x=-a$ and $y=-b$ where $a,b$ are positive. Now we have:
\begin{eqnarray} xy &=& (-a)(-b)\\ &=& (-1)a(-1)b\\ 
&=& (-1)(-1)ab \\ &=& 1\cdot ab \\&=& ab>0\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @Aelx Yes I did, so?

Comment: Where is that said? It is not about (-1)(-1) is 1,  you already know that. @Aelx

Comment: You're right, I've misread the question. Seems like he takes that as an already proven fact.